# adding new Input to jquery validationEngine form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I have some fairly complex ajax logic etc going on in the `onValidationComplete` function for a form with [jQuery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine).

This is working perfect, but one thing is bothering me.

in the form I have the ability to dynamically add inputs (add new row button).

so my code structure wise looks like:

var form = $('#myForm');

```
form.validationEngine('attach', {onValidationComplete:validationComplete});
$('#newInput').on('click', function(){
    form.append('<input />');
    form.validationEngine('detach');
    form.validationEngine('attach', {onValidationComplete:validationComplete});
});

function validationComplete(form, status){/*all my logic here*/}
```

What I don't like about it is that every time I add a new input I have to detach and then re-attach the `validationEngine`.

Is there any way to just tell it to add the new input to it's list of inputs to validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method?

Comment: Care to add more detail? use it in what context?

Comment: Plugin for validation you are using uses .bind() to attach validation event to the form fields. It does not work on dynamically created elements. Check [plugin](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/js/jquery.validationEngine.js) on lines 62-65, and try changing bind() to either on(), delegate() or live(). But keep in mind live() is deprecated from jQuery 1.7+